Proto-Semitic bound masculine dual noun suffix
This article is about a proposal regarding the origins of the Biblical Hebrew 3rd-person plural masculine suffix <־יו> /Caːw/. Under section 5 (“A New Proposal”), the author claims that the (late) Proto-Semitic bound masculine dual noun suffix, reconstructed as /-aːj/, originates from (early) Proto-Semitic /-al/.
Where does the reconstruction /-al/ come from? I haven’t been able to find any support for it, but the author seems to take it as a given.

/-aI-/ isn't a suffix, it's the dual ending. This became -ayim in the absolute state in Hebrew (with mimation and segolation) and (according to the authors) -ē in the construct/bound state, repurposed as the plural ending instead. It's pretty silly to write it as /-aI-/ rather than just /-ay-/, though—it's not like Proto-Semitic had i/y allophony.

I think you’re slightly misreading the article. You can’t tell the difference here, where a default sans-serif font is used, but the /-aI/ in the article has an uppercase i (i.e., it’s /-aI/), not a lowercase L (/-al/) the way you’ve written it in the question. So it’s not an L becoming /j/, but an i becoming (or being identical with) /j), which is much more straightforward.

Janus' comment is obviously right and might well have been a formal answer. I just want to add that they explain their usage under 4.2 (page 15):
"The task of this section will be to describe the dimensional (and, where appropriate, the gestural) specifications of the high vocoids, I and U. We use these sigla to capture the significant phonological observation that the approximants w and y demonstrate significant featural overlap with their respectively corresponding high vowels u and i."

@JanusBahsJacquet Thank you! If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

@QwertyCTRL. Done! (Also with incorporation of the section quoted by pinnerup above.)

This question appears to be based on a misreading of the article. The sans-serif font used on this site obfuscates the difference to the eye, but copy-pasting the text in the question into a code editor makes it clear that the question writes /-al/ (with a lowercase L at the end).
A (usually conditioned) change /l/ > /j/ is not particularly uncommon cross-linguistically. Within Indo-European languages, for example, Latin -īlia regularly becomes French -ille /-ij(ə)/), and even within Semitic languages, there are clear, even synchronic examples of it – e.g., the Amharic root K-F-L forms the base of the verb ከፈለ käffälä ‘split, divide; pay’, whose imperative is ክፈይ kəfäy(i) ‘pay!, split!’, with the /l/ becoming /j/ before the high front vowel /i/ (which is then subsequently optionally deleted).
However, that is not what is at play here. Rather, it is simply that the original article writes /-aI/ (with an uppercase i at the end) rather than /-al/, so the intended phoneme is in fact a palatal (semi)vowel very similar to /j/, not a lateral consonant.
As @pinnerup notes in their comment, the article justifies this choice of notation on page 15 in section 4.2:

The task of this section will be to describe the dimensional (and, where appropriate, the gestural) specifications of the high vocoids, I and U. We use these sigla to capture the significant phonological observation that the approximants w and y demonstrate significant featural overlap with their respectively corresponding high vowels u and i. […] In its various manifestations (i and y), the phoneme I is realized as [+high, –back, –round] in traditional phonological descriptions. Similarly, u and w derive from a segment U, whose phonetic expression displays the features [+high, +back, +round].

In other words, when the authors write /I/, they basically mean ‘either /i/ or /j/, as appropriate’, so it’s really only a matter of (early) Proto-Semitic /-aj/ becoming (late) Proto-Semitic /-aːj/ for this morpheme.
